# WindowScroller + AutoSizer + List not working as expected

Tags: react-virtualized

I was trying to use the combination of the WindowScroller + AutoSizer + List on my web application. The virtualization works well when it is only AutoSizer + List. However, when I put it inside the WindowScroller, the list of rows no longer display properly.

This is how it looks when WindowScroller is applied.
[list result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2R9d.png)

I already searched for available solutions here and on the doc. Found similar problem posted here but the answer provided was already been applied on my code. Now, I can't figure out what exactly hinders the display of the rows.

```js
return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <WindowScroller>
          {({height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop}) => (
            <AutoSizer disableHeight>
              {({width}) => (
                <List
                  autoHeight
                  height={height}
                  isScrolling={isScrolling}
                  onScroll={onChildScroll}
                  rowCount={rows.length}
                  rowHeight={30}
                  rowRenderer={({ index, style }) => <div style={style}>Row {index}</div>}
                  scrollTop={scrollTop}
                  width={width}
                >
                </List>
              )}
            </AutoSizer>
          )}
        </WindowScroller>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is an implementation issue. The overflow style of the container element which I was using for the reference of the WindowScroller is not set properly.

Comment: did you find a solution?